# Does affine open set equal to distinguished open subset in an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

For $A$ a commutative ring, does it always hold that all affine open subschemes of $\text{Spec }A$ lie over a distinguished open subset of $\text{Spec} A$?

Comment: It seems this was answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/133474

Comment: @Prospect Got it, thanks a lot.